# Lua: is [^%d%u] equal to [%D%U]?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

As in the title:
in Lua programming language is [^%d%u] equal to [%D%U] in it's buildin regular expressions ?

I would say it is but I suspect that this question is asked in the book

```
Programming in Lua, Fourth Edition
Roberto Ierusalimschy
Copyright © 2016, 2003 Roberto Ierusalimschy
```

on the page 89 for a reason.
But I can't think about any reason why those would be different.

Comment: No, these are different patterns. `[^%d%u]` matches any char other than digit and uppercase letters. `[%D%U]` matches any chars since it matches any non-digit or any non-uppercase letter. In a negated bracket expression, the relationship is AND and in a positive bracket expression, it is OR.

Answer (score 3):

These are different patterns.

- `[^%d%u]` matches *any char other than digit **and** uppercase letters*. So it matches `.` and `_` and `a`, but does not match `0` and `A`.
- `[%D%U]` matches *any chars* since it matches any non-digit **or** any non-uppercase letter.

Note that in a negated bracket expression (`[^...]`), the relationship between the patterns inside it is **AND** and in a positive bracket expression (`[...]`), it is **OR**.